# Filter Facebook Business Pages by Location

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am building a Facebook scraper accessible to an API using puppeteer and node.js

Essentially I have succeeded in scraping all the data contained in pages of this format https://www.facebook.com/search/pages?q=roofing

Now within the same page I want to scrape out data by location.

There is a location filter on the left panel which is essentially an input with aria-label="Location"

I have tried several ways of opening up that input(using click events,changing the html etc) but it just doesn't change.

Also there is no way to achieve this via query params(eg location="texas")

If you try doing something like this:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Location"]').focus()
```

or

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Location"]').value = "blah blah"
```

won't work

How then can I filter out fb business pages using Javascript?[image: specified page]

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: To be fair its a simple problem which I can't seem to understand. All I want is to either open up the input to type or find a way to do it through query params.

Comment: have you checked if filters change the URL?

Comment: @catasaurus Yes they do but it is an encoded string which has no use. Guess it is part of fb system to prevent custom scripts from getting access to their APIs